# C# Triple DES in ECB Decrypt Issues

Tags: c#, php, encryption, des, ecb

I have this PHP script which we need to convert to C# to decode a result from an API post request, but I am experiencing issues with my C# implementation.

We get the result fine while running the PHP script which is `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX` but get different errors.

Values are:

```
encodedText = "U8Q+m2zpFMLa/3gYILHx5w=="
key = "examplesecret"
keyHash = "6315046b2c085bbeeab87c65"
```

Php Script:

```
<?php
$secret = 'examplesecret';
$encrypted_code = 'U8Q+m2zpFMLa/3gYILHx5w==';
// Base64
// Decode
$encrypted_code = base64_decode( $encrypted_code );
// Create decryption module
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open( 'tripledes', '', 'ecb', '' );
$keysize = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size( $cipher ); // = 24
// Generate key
$hash = md5( $secret );
$key = substr( $hash, 0, $keysize );
// Initialise decrypter
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv( mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size( $cipher ),
MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM );
mcrypt_generic_init( $cipher, $key, $iv );
// Decrypt code
$decrypted = mdecrypt_generic( $cipher, $encrypted_code );
// Output decrypted code
echo $decrypted;
?>
```

C# Script

```
public static string Decrypt(string encodedText, string key)
{
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] byteHash;
    byte[] byteBuff;

    byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    desCryptoProvider.Key = byteHash;
    desCryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    desCryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
    byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText);

    var byteHex = BitConverter.ToString(byteBuff).Replace("-", " ");

    string plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(desCryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteHex, 0, byteHex.Length));
    return plaintext;
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Exception Error: "Bad Data.\r\n"

Comment: 3DES + ECB mode == insecure. 3DES should not be used in new work, it is superceeded by AES. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: MD5 is not secure for deriving a key from a password,use PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2).

Comment: This code is so bad that you should throw it away and just use RNCryptor which has a PHP library and a C# library.

Comment: @zaph Some great points raised here and myself and OP agree (we work together). For info, this is part of an interface into an API that we have no control over and client has provided the PHP code to us. Neither me nor Michael know anything about PHP or encryption which is why this has stumped us. And no, the client is not able to provide us a C# version.

Comment: You can always say "No" to the client. The choice is to say no or create key poor security. Ask yourself what a professional would do. A client who tells the structural engineer to use smaller beams. The structural engineer who tells the electrical engineer to use smaller wiring. What would these professionals do?

Comment: @zaph Under any other circumstance I would do that (exactly the kind of thing I tell people on here all the time, and I am already going to push for this to be changed) unfortunately it's a third party that our client wants us to work with and we have little say in the matter.

Comment: Let's just go with the under sized beams, I'm sure that's what the structural engineer would do—oh, probably not. OK, perhaps have the electrician design the beams. This is only about compromised security of the uses, not ours so no problem, right? One is either part of the solution or part of the problem, we all need to decide which part we are.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things I see:

1. You derive `$key` via a substr in PHP; but just take the output of MD5 in C#, are they the same? (e.g. if PHP's value was a hex string, then the 16 bytes of MD5 are 32 characters, which gets trunctated to 24 characters, being a 12-byte (96-bit) value; in C# it's 16 bytes)
2. Speaking of the keys, if you're using PHP before 5.6, a deficient key was 0-padded (per the documentation of [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php); C# won't do that for you.  So that's another thing to check.
3. You have an IV in the PHP code, but ECB doesn't use an IV. That won't be causing your problem here, but it's less than ideal.
4. Of course, I should at this point warn that ECB is "too stable" and doesn't hide patterns in encrypted data, and doesn't hide that you're sending the same message again.
5. TransformFinalBlock takes bytes, but you seem to be giving it a string here.  Since C# is a strongly typed language, this can't really be the code you're running.
6. You should avoid talking about the specific implementations of algorithms.  `TripleDES.Create()` is preferred to `new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()`, `MD5.Create()` over `new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()`; and type the variables as just TripleDES and MD5.
7. The TripleDES object, the MD5 object, and the output of CreateDecryptor() are all IDisposable, so you should really wrap them in a using statement to be more efficient with your native resources.

The most likely culprit for your problem, though, is that you're not generating the same key in both languages.